# WordPress Multsite Network site under another network site

Tags: multisite

Is it possible to have a multisite under another one?

`networksite.com/site1/site2/`

I know that you cannot just type in an additional sub-directory when creating a new site in the network.

For example, if this was for a college it would be:`college.edu/undergraduate/program`. Where "undergraduate" would be a sub-site and "program" would be its own sub-site as well. This would create a logical link structure on the front-end and make user permissions and organization easier on the back-end.

Any ideas, code, workarounds etc. are appreciated!

Comment: Keep in mind the WPMU reached end of life with WP 3.x once the multisite feature was added to WP, you'll confuse people by referring to multisite and multi-network installs as WPMU, especially given that WPMU is also a company in the WP ecosystem. Plugin reccomendations are also offtopic here

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell, sorry about the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

I heard about this plugin at the latest WordCamp in Vienna. It allows you to create a network of networks: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! This seems like the perfect solution, although I'm encountering some issues with the subsites of a network, namely that they show 404 errors once created. It looks like the plugin hasn't been updated in a while, and not a lot of issues being answered on the plugin site.